# Android app force close when network shifts from wifi to edge or any other network

Tags: android, wifi, gprs, cellular-network

I am developing an app which requires internet.

So my issue is that when a user shifts its network from Wi-Fi to EDGE or to GPRS or some other network then my app crashes. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add logs and code that causes the crash.

Comment: I dont have gprs or 3g 2g activated it is hapenning on my client side since he has dat activated... i was thinking of some logical help may be der is some action or permission to be placed in manifest which usually comes out to be a one line code

Comment: It can be anything, really. You should at least reproduce it locally or get crash report (if you are using Android Market, this is sent to you automatically on crash). This will at least point you to correct part of code.

Comment: With which error-message does your App crash?